# Drupal 7 show current displayed node field in block

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Can someone pls guide me with this?

I have five images associated with a node which I have kept hidden. I want to show them in a block.

How do I show the images in the block belonging to the CURRENTLY DISPLAYED NODE?
So that as the node changes, it will automatically load the images of that node on the block?
I figured this has got to do with adding filters.

But I cant seem to get any
**'current node'** filter as such when I was seeing those lists.
I also read that I can pass an argument of the current node to the block. But In drupal 7, there is no such field called 'arguments' while editing the block....

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that using [views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

1- Create a new views block.

2- Under `Fields` section, choose your images field.

3- Under `Contextual filters` click `Add` then choose `Content: Nid`

4- Under `When the filter value is NOT available` choose `Provide default value` then `Content ID from URL`, then click `Apply`.

5- Save your view and go to the blocks manager page `admin/structure/block` and click `configure` beside your new views block.

6- Navigate to the bottom of the page to `Content types`, then check the content types you wanna have this block to be shown.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Basically, this is probably the easiest way to go. If the OP can't go the views route, I think they'd have to make a custom template file for the content type.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It did help. And brought with it something else too. The slideshow isnt working for the view, although it seems Ive done all the requisites. Anyways, that would call for a different question. Thanks again :)

Comment: Really glad it helped. For `views slideshow` part, make sure you download `jquery cycle plugin` and put it under `sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle`... Let me know the results :). -Muhammad.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks very much, this helped a lot. I have a further question though: As well as only displaying the block with fields from the current node, can you also hide the block for a node that has no values in this particular field? Thanks very much.

Comment: @Janico; A quick solution is to add a new Filter from `Filter criteria`, then add a condition that your field is `Is not empty (NOT NULL)`. This should hide the view when the field is empty.